# Change View with NavigationViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, popviewcontrolleranimated

all this is probably a trivial question, but I have not found a solution to it. I am making an app for Iphone using Swift.

I have a tableview with some strings and if I press a button I want to navigate back to the previous view directly. However, the code after my call

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

is always run, but I want the current activity to stop and go back to the previous view.

The code looks like:

```
    @IBAction func DeletePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let deleteIndices = getIndexToDelete()
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    print("After navigationController")
    for index in deleteIndices{
        results?.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day[dayShownIndex].results.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
    if (results?.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day[dayShownIndex].results.count == 0){
        results?.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day.removeAtIndex(dayShownIndex)
    }
    if (results?.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day.count == 0){
        results?.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months.removeAtIndex(monthShownIndex)
    }
    if (results?.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months.count == 0){
        results?.ListResults.removeAtIndex(monthShownIndex)
    }
    loadView()
}
```

"After navigationController" is always displayed.

In android you would start a new activity by creating intents to get the desired behaviour, but how does it work on Iphone?

My problem is that I want to be able to go back directly when `navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated` is called. This is just a toy example to understand how it works so that I can use it in the if-clauses later.

Comment: What do you want to do? navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) will move you back to the previous view

Comment: What are you wanting to do, popViewController will take you back but what is the code underneath? What is your problem, you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply add a `return` statement after you pop the viewcontroller:

```
@IBAction func DeletePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let deleteIndices = getIndexToDelete()
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    return;
    [...]
```

Comment: The print statement is still executed, but the if-clauses not. Seems a bit strange.

Comment: this is weird. are you sure that there is no other print statement that gets executed? normally `return` should end the function...

Comment: Yes, I thought the same and changed that particular print statement, but the output changed as well, so it is really that statement.

Comment: I also added a print statement after the if-clauses, that is NOT executed. I have recompiled it several times.

Comment: now i know: you have to add a semicolon after the return statement. otherwise the line **after** the return statement is treated as an argument of the return statement and - in this case - therefore printed. check my updated answer!

Comment: Wow, thanks. I am also learning swift as you might notice. ;)

Comment: Is it by the way so you are supposed to do? Not like Android where you create intents and start activities?

Comment: i'm not sure what exactly you mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wants to execute code after "print("After navigationController")" then remove that code

or it is not possible to remove then toggle it when DeletePressed called

Comment: Well, it is a toy example which I must understand the behaviour of. Sometimes I want to go back and sometimes I want to stay in that view. Now I want to go back everytime so that I know that it works, and I do not want the program to call print("After navigationController")